# PHP : JWT How to use JWT without composer

Tags: php, jwt

PHP- JWT without composer.

I wanted to use JWT in my PHP code-igniter 4 project without composer

Comment: So you don't have run permissions in the server?

Comment: It's a pretty absurd requirement to not use composer, so it might help you clarify why

Comment: Anything that composer installs can be installed manually by copying and pasting the same files. Composer is just a labour-saving device, that's all

Comment: @ADyson I did the same way, BTW thank you.